# Icmp protocol questions

Tags: c#, networking

I'm currently experimenting with the Icmp protocol and I would like to implement a new class `IcmpPacket`.
I read about the protocol on Wikipedia and I also found an article about pinging with Icmp on MSDN.
I'm a bit confused because of some differences between both websites.

Wikipedia defines the structure of a Icmp packet as the following:
1 Byte Type
1 Byte Code
2 Byte Checksum
4 Byte Rest of header (whatever this is)

On MSDN there is an example given for such an `IcmpPacket` class (extract of the class)

```
public class IcmpPacket { 
    public byte Type;
    public byte SubCode;
    public UInt16 CheckSum;
    public UInt16 Identifier;
    public UInt16 SequenceNumber;
    public byte[] Data;
}
```

the first three attributes are clear but what about `Identifier` and `SequenceNumber` (=> Rest of header?)

Another question I got is if I would like to use an `IcmpPacket` to ping a server, do I really need `Identifier`, `SequenceNumber` and `Data`? (My hoster said that the smallest IcmpPacket possible is about 28Bytes large, so if taking `Identifier` and `SequenceNumber`, do I have to fill the remaining 20 Bytes with `Data`?)

P.S.: Is there maybe a website out which well describes the structure if Icmp?

Comment: for the structure, hit up [IETF](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/search/?name=icmp&rfcs=on&activeDrafts=on&search_submit=) , you will find all the specs there.

Comment: You will find both are correct, because the C# class does not represent the final packet generated and sent on the wire. As @Moses suggested, you should read IETF RFC documents if you want to learn the packet format. Besides, capture some network packets with Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark when you ping a device is also helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what about Identifier and SequenceNumber?

Identifier and SequenceNumber are values meaningful to your implementation to match echo requests with the corresponding echo replies.  RFC 792 offers a suggestion for using them...

```
  For example, the identifier might be used like a port in TCP or UDP to
  identify a session, and the sequence number might be incremented
  on each echo request sent.  The echoer returns these same values
  in the echo reply.
```

> if I would like to use an IcmpPacket to ping a server, do I really need Identifier, SequenceNumber and Data?

Identifier, SequenceNumber and Data fields must exist in the frame...

> My hoster said that the smallest IcmpPacket possible is about 28Bytes large, so if taking Identifier and SequenceNumber, do I have to fill the remaining 20 Bytes with Data?

If they are talking about a 28 byte IPv4 packet, then the smallest packet must include the minimum 20-byte IPv4 header + 8 bytes of ICMP header.

> Is there maybe a website out which well describes the structure if Icmp?

You should read [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792#page-14) online...